# VMWare Player installation on NixOS

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I downloaded the `VMware-Player-15.1.0-13591040.x86_64.bundle` file from: https://www.vmware.com/go/getplayer-linux

Then I followed these instructions for installing it: https://www.linuxlookup.com/howto/install_vmware_workstation_or_vmware_player_bundle_file

When I run:

```
sudo sh VMware-Player-15.1.0-13591040.x86_64.bundle
```

I get the following error:

> [neo@nixos:~/Downloads]$ sudo sh
>   VMware-Player-15.1.0-13591040.x86_64.bundle [sudo] password for neo: 
>   Extracting VMware Installer...done.
>   /tmp/vmis.tYIuh4/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: line 56:
>   /tmp/vmis.tYIuh4/install/vmware-installer/vmis-launcher: No such file
>   or directory

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the MD5 or SHA hash of your download?

A corrupted download might cause this type of error.

Comment: How am I supposed to check the hash of the download if they do not give its value on the download page?

Comment: Ah.. you used the "try player download" page. You are correct, they do not mention it down there. It's very convenient to download from, except for not having any other details. If you go to the following page then you get all the extra details such as the checksums. https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/15_0

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run an ELF binary file on NixOS and it cannot find the interpreter (which is actually located in the NixOS store). You'll need to patch the binary for NixOS. See the [patch ELF wiki page](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html).

The "No such file or directory" is a non-descriptive error referencing the interpreter.